# Moving BxSlider buttons into position

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bxslider

I am using a bxslider on my webpage. Although the buttons on the side for prev/next are off. Is there a way to move the buttons on the image slider back into place?

my site: http://rootforsite.azurewebsites.net/

regards

Answer (score 0):

you can overwirte the CSS for the buttons using this selectors: **.bx-wrapper .bx-prev, .bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover** and **.bx-wrapper .bx-next, .bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover**. Position them using margins, or left/ right, depending on where you wanna have them.